# Showing irrationality of $\zeta(k)$ for some $k$ without calculating the value.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

For $s\in (1,\infty)$ let $\zeta(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac 1{n^s}$.

Is there a way to show that $\zeta(2k)$ is irrational for some integer $k\geq 1$ without finding explicit formulae?

Comment: Would you allow calculations of other series?

Comment: $\zeta(3)\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ by Apery's proof.

Comment: @fretty : yes off-course

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio : But that is actually harder than even calulating $\zeta (2) $ and conclude it is irrational :P

Comment: I guess the point being made is that Apery's proof is independent of actually calculating $\zeta(3)$ (which is what you asked for).

Comment: @fretty : Yes I get the point  :) but you know I was wishing to get something simpler ...

Comment: My guess is that it is probably even harder than Apery's proof to find a SIMPLE proof independent of calculation. I was thinking of using the link with the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$ since $\eta(1) = \ln(2)$ which is easily seen to be irrational. However I am not sure whether it is so easy to find any other values of eta at a positive integer WITHOUT knowing $\zeta$ values in advance.

Comment: Oh no I was wrong, I can prove $\zeta(4)$ is irrational without calculating it.

Comment: @fretty: truly ? can you do it ?

Comment: I have posted an answer, it is probably not the easiest but it works.

Comment: Is this answer satisfactory?

Answer (score 2):

I can prove $\zeta(4)$ is irrational without needing to calculate it.

Consider for $z$ in the upper half plane the weight $4$ Eisenstein series:

$G_4(z) = \sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\backslash (0,0)}\frac{1}{(mz+n)^4}$

It has a Fourier expansion:

$G_4(z) = 2\zeta(4) + \frac{16\pi^4}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_{3}(n) q^n$

where $q = e^{2\pi i z}$ and $\sigma_3(n) = \sum_{d\mid n}d^3$. Assuming we know that $\pi^4$ is irrational (which follows from the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental) then it is clear that all Fourier coefficients for $n\geq 1$ are irrational.

---

Also consider the theta series $\theta_{E_8}(z)$ for the $E_8$ lattice. This has a Fourier expansion:

$\theta_{E_8}(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r(n) q^n$

where the $r(n)$ values are all integers (they measure numbers of vectors in $E_8$ of a given norm).

---

Here is the magic, both $G_4, \theta_{E_8}$ are modular forms of weight $4$ for the modular group SL$_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

However it is known that the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of such functions is $1$-dimensional. Thus $\theta_{E_8} = \alpha G_4$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. So in particular there is a number $\alpha$ that scales all Fourier coefficients of $G_4$ to be integers.

But if we suppose $\zeta(4)\in\mathbb{Q}$ then we hit a problem since then the Fourier coefficients of $G_4$ would be a mixture of rational and irrational and no such scaling could then simultaneously produce integers (if $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational then at most one of $\alpha x, \alpha y$ can be rational for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^{\times}$).

Actually it is easy to get the usual formula $\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$ from the equality $\theta_{E_8}(z) = \alpha G_4$.

Comment: don't you need to assume that $\pi^4$ is irrational ?

Comment: Yeah I should have been more careful (although it would follow from $\pi$ being transcendental). But I am sure I am allowed to assume this.

Comment: To be honest I tried to make this answer to be as concrete as possible by being able to write down the Fourier expansions explicitly. It general I imagine you can show that $\zeta(2k)$ is irrational for all $k\geq 1$ by arguing that the Eisenstein subspace of $M_{k}(\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ is $1$-dimensional and contains a form with rational Fourier coefficients. I am just not sure if the proof of these facts uses the formula for $\zeta(2k)$ (to get normalized Eisenstein series which fit the bill).

Comment: Sorry $k\geq 2$. Then it is just a case of showing that $\zeta(2)$ is irrational.

Comment: This can also be tackled. Consider the weight $2$ Eisenstein series: $G_2(z) = 2\zeta(2) + 8\pi^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma(n)q^n$. This is NOT a modular form but according to Diamond/Shurman p.$18$ the function $G_{2,N}(z) := G_{2}(z) - NG_{2}(Nz)$ is a weight $2$ modular form for $\Gamma_0(N)$ for any $N$. Choosing $N=p$ prime we find that the constant term is $(2-2p)\zeta(2) \neq 0$. Then we note that the Eisenstein subspace of $M_2(\Gamma_0(p))$ is known to be $1$-dimensional for any prime. The same argument as above applies. Obviously we are still assuming we know $\pi$ is transcendental